# Changing the default order of products on category view

Tags: magento2

I want to change the default category sorting from whatever it is by default to NEWSEST FIRST. Seems like there is no way to set this in the backend, so how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I think there are two ways.

1. Create your own sort option in a module using a plugin. Something like this: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/96095/magento-2-how-to-add-custom-sort-by-option. Look at Luca S's answer. I think this person has a general idea of how to do it.
2. Use Position option but modified:
   http://magento2x.com/magento-sort-newest-products-solution/.

I dont like how they both override stuff, but hopefully this will give you a starting point. Good Luck.

Comment: Lucas Answer doesn't seem to work, also theres no real explenation. However, thanks for both links. Second link links to Mage1 solution, which is not needed here.